# 使用して and 使って difference

Tags: grammar, wago-and-kango

what is the difference between these two terms.The actual use of them ?
for eg. are トランジスタを使用して and トランジスタを使って same ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34468/9831

Comment: Also related (regarding the difference of wago and kango): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13783/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3547/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23156/9831

Answer (score 2):

While there is no difference in *meaning* per se, there is definitely a difference in *tone* between the two. You may also benefit from looking up the differences in usage between [漢語]{かんご} and [和語]{わご}, but there are already many threads on that so I won't touch on it here explicitly.

使う is most often used in speech (both polite and casual) and casual written language:

> A) もう使い終わりましたか？ - Are you done yet?
>
> B) うん、どうぞ。- Yeah, go ahead (and use it).

A few minutes later

> A) これを使ってもいいですか？ - May I use this?
>
> B) もう使っていいって。 - I already said you could use it.

使用する is most often used in formal written language and very formal spoken language.

> ご使用前にラベルをよく読み、[安全使用上]{あんぜんしようじょう}の[注意]{ちゅうい}に[従]{したが}ってご使用ください。 - Before use, please review the safe use warning on the label and use (the product) accordingly.
>
> [増税]{ぞうぜい}による[差額]{さがく}の２％分は[未払い]{みばらい}の[状況]{じょうきょう}なので、使用[時]{じ}に店から[支払い]{しはらい}を[求]{もと}められる[可能性]{かのうせい}はあります。 - Because the 2% difference in price arising from the (consumption) tax increase effectively hasn't been paid yet, you may be asked to pay this difference at the register when you try to use (your prepaid meal ticket).

There are also two other verbs that translate into the basic use of "to use" in English: [利用]{りよう}する and [用いる]{もちいる}.

利用する is used to imply that someone benefits from using something, or that they're using something for personal gain (like another person), so this can have positive or negative connotations.

用いる is, in my experience, only used in an academic setting, and so sounds even more formal than 使用する.

So to answer your question, bothトランジスターを使用して/使用し and トランジスターを使って/使い are perfectly fine meaning-wise, but they would both be used in slightly different contexts. If this was going in an academic paper/presentation you may also consider using トランジスターを用いて/用い.